# How to find Steering Flow of a tropical cyclone?

Tags: tropical-cyclone, cyclone

I am wondering a method to find the steering flow of a tropical cyclone from wind data?

Comment: My guess is that kind of things are calculated at supercomputers with very complicated equations, but I migth be wrong.